# Can an iPhone be restored from an iPod Touch backup?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, backup

If I have an iPod Touch backup on my computer, can an iPhone restore from it? How about vice versa?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[According to this forums post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=527801), somebody did it with success.

> **Worked flawlessly for me**
>   I just activated my new iPhone 3GS and then iTunes offered to either set it up as a new iPhone or to restore it from my iPod Touch backup which I did. No problems so far...

Comment: The only issue I can think of would be if the device you're restoring TO has lower firmware than the device that made the backup. iTunes usually rejects that. (This would be very unlikely in an iPod Touch to iPhone restore though.)

In my experience, if there are files lacking in the restore that the iPhone needs (carrier info, etc) they're just created as if it was a factory reset -- impressively robust decision by whoever did that on the iOS team ;)  After the restore, you may see the iOS loading bar like you would after a reset -- that's ok, it's just those files being filled in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i can confirm this Works based on my experience. All my music and contacts from my iPod touch was magically restored to the iPhone 4S.

Answer (score 0):

It will depends only of the iOS version, because the Apple's script is not accepting iOS minor than 8 right now (That's called downgrade). But if want to make an "Upgrade" (or restore from a version to the same version) so you have no problem with that, even with different devices.